# Data type in SQL Server database for storing big JSON

Tags: sql-server, json

What is the best data type in Microsoft SQL Server database for storing big JSON (minimum 8000 characters) in one variable? I will need it later for saving, parsing and retrieving data.

Comment: `varchar(MAX)` stores a maximum of 2,147,483,647 characters. Which is more than 8000

Comment: 2^31-1 ? thanks for the news :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

If it was XML you could have stored it as XML and run queries directly.

It is really bad that Microsoft has not added support for JSON yet, even in 2014.

Comment: right, thanks.. JSON is necessary now